# How to remove or exclude components from JavaScript variable before using it in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a webpage that contains ASP.NET panels and JavasScript that expands and collapses them when the user clicks the expand/collapse all button. I want to exclude some panels so they don't get expanded or collapsed when the user clicks the button (they are contained in a user control and appear as nested panels).

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function expandCollapsePanels() 
{
    var collapse = $('#<%= lbltogglePanels.ClientID %>').html() == "Collapse all panels";
    var panels = Sys.Application.getComponents();

    for (var i in panels) 
    {
        //if panel name/ID contains 'pnlDetails', remove it (or don't collapse/expand it)

        panels[i].set_Collapsed(collapse);
    }
}
```

How can I modify this code to remove panels that contain 'pnlDetails' as part of their ID(or element name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 for (var i in panels) 
    {
        //if panel name/ID contains 'pnlDetails', remove it (or don't collapse/expand it)
        if(panels[i].name.indexOf("pnlDetails") > -1 || panels[i].ID.indexOf("pnlDetails") > -1){
            panels[i].set_Collapsed(collapse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes something like that, but if the .name contains 'pnlDetails' as part of the name as that's what the all of the panels have as part of their name. How do you modify the code to check if the name contains that?